# Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server .Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, iis-express

I have a .net core 2.2 application configured to run under IIS:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ProgramExtensions.ConfigureTypeConverters();
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

And also in `.csproj` configured to run **in process**:

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

For some reason when running it under **IIS Express** I'm getting:

> InvalidOperationException: Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server.

[image]

What might be the reason of the error?

Comment: Remove `.UseIISIntegration()`. You don't need it anyway and I expect it's confusing things.

Comment: What is your `ProgramExtensions.ConfigureTypeConverters();`?Did you biuld and run successfully in local host?Have you installed the .net core IIS hosting bundle? You could refer to [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2).And what is your web.config?

Comment: I'm just clicking on **IIS Express** debugging button in visual studio for running the app, there is no web.config. What actually does that button click behind the scene?

Comment: @Grigoryants Artem  have you found a solution for this?